# Refreshing the order of the Listbox when item's details has changed

Tags: wpf

How can I re-sort my Listbox when an item's name is changed using MVVM?

My Listbox is bound to an Observable collection that stores a 'People' class that inherits INotifyPropertyChanged. The Listbox is sorted on property 'Name' and when I change the value of 'Name' for one of the items in the Listbox, I can see that it's value has changed but the Listbox does not automatically re-sort itself.

The initial sorting is done through a CollectionViewSource

```
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="SortedItems" Source="{Binding PeopleList}">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Name"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
```

and is used by the Listbox as follows

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SortedItems}}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentSelectedPerson}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

When I go to a different page and come back the Listbox has the correct ordering, but when I change the Name of the person the Listbox doesn't refresh. How can this be done while preserving MVVM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this is a known problem which i guess is not been addressed yet.Try implementing a custom CollectionViewSource as mentioned in the below link

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/d7eda358-ca16-4164-8773-fd92527c7795

also check this thread for an alternative

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/cb7c5c62-7ca9-49b5-91a0-379581b1c1aa/

Comment: A link from your first link gave me the solution I implemented. I just removed/added the object from the ObservableCollection. It's not the most elegant solution but it didn't require the inheritance/implementatino of a new interface so it seemed the cleanest and fastest.